# How can I get UISegementedControl functionality with custom UIButtons?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have created my own custom filter view which I want to act like a UISegmentedControl. I have set it up as a view and then 3 UIButtons. I want to know how I can make it so when one is clicked the other two are deselected and the api call for that button is made which then reloads the UICollectionView beneath it.

Here is a picture of my view with the 3 buttons to hopefully better explain what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share some code. Also, why not just use a `UISegmentedControl` as per the HIG?

Comment: I'm new to iOS so I'm asking more how I approach this than how to fix a particular problem. I didn't use the `UISegmentedControl` as I wasn't aware that I could get it to look like the image above and thought it's design customisation was limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect all your buttons to this `IBAction` and define tag to each button.

```
- (IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender {

    UIButton* button1 = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:99];
    UIButton* button2 = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
    UIButton* button3 = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:101];

    [button1 setEnabled:NO];
    [button2 setEnabled:NO];
    [button3 setEnabled:NO];

    [button1 setSelected:NO];
    [button2 setSelected:NO];
    [button3 setSelected:NO];

    if([sender tag]==99){
        [button1 setSelected:YES];
        [button1 setEnabled:YES];
    }else if([sender tag]==100){
        [button2 setSelected:YES];
        [button2 setEnabled:YES];
    }else{
        [button3 setSelected:YES];
        [button3 setEnabled:YES];
    }

}
```

Comment: SetEnabled have to be inverted: [button1 setEnabled:YES];
    [button2 setEnabled:YES];
    [button3 setEnabled:YES];

Comment: if([sender tag]==99){
        [button1 setSelected:YES];
        [button1 setEnabled:NO];
} etc.

Comment: Was just about to write asking this. Thanks. This now works with no problems.